# Symfony: FOS user Bundle promote user via controller

Tags: symfony

I am new to FOS user bundle. 
I have user and want to create a function to promote them (which will do the same than:

```
php app/console fos:user:promote testuser ROLE_MANAGER
```

my security.yml is:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MANAGER:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:         [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Any idea how to do that from a controller?
I created a UserBundle with a UserController.php to extend FOS user and create a profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
public function promoteUserAction(){

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');    
    $user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    $userManager->updateUser($user);

    return $this->render('ACMEBundle:User:page.html.twig');
}
```

Hope it will be useful for others.
cheers

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you happen to only know the FOS username and you want to promote the user being logged in as a different user (the accepted answer promotes the logged in user), you can use this sample code:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('username' => 'gauss'));
$user->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

In this case, I'm searching for the FOS username of 'gauss' and promoting use gauss to ROLE_ADMIN. You can then run a sql command of `select id,username,roles from fos_user;` on your database to verify the role has been added.

Hopefully this helps someone.